# How can I migrate a Locally hosted Wordpress site to a remote host?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wp-admin

I have a website on my locally hosted XAMMP server (Windows). I need to transfer this over to 123Reg.

The XAMPP server runs: PHP 7.3.2 and MySQL 5.5.5; and the 123Reg server runs:PHP 7.2.16 and MySQL 5.5.5

I have tried using Duplicator. It works however I cannot access the Wordpress backend (wp-admin) using any admin credentials or make a new one in the Duplicator wizard and via the database (it would just say 'Sorry, you can't access this page', and yes, I have tried deleting plugins and editing the .htaccess file with no luck). I have tried a manual migration (export and restore files and database) as well with the same issue as the duplicator one.

Currently, I have installed a new version of Wordpress on the 123Reg server can copied the wp-content directory from the XAMPP server to the 123Reg one. However, this is not enough. I need the whole site (including pages), cloned so they look exactly as they are on the XAMPP server on the 123Reg server.

I was expecting it to transfer the site without errors as the site is fine on my XAMMP server, but it's not.

Am I doing something wrong? I am not sure of what to do now so I would appreciate any sort of help.